# Get the Correct Object Based on Type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to SpringBoot and I am creating Project which has capability to call multiple QueryEngine i.e run query in for different Source.

I Create `QueryEngine` Interface :

```
public interface QueryEngine
{

    public void runQuery(String Query);
}
```

Now I have class which implement this interface like

```
BigQueryEngine
MSSQLEngine
PrestoEngine
```

All these class will implement the `runQuery` Method.

Now in my controller when someone will hit my api `/run/query`:
and will pass this :

```
{
  Query : ""
  Engine : "BigQuery"
}
```

My Service class method is :

```
@Autowired
 public QueryEngine queryEngine;
public void runQuery(String query, String type) {
  
        queryEngine.runQuery(query);
    
}
```

What is the correct way to get the correct Class based on Type ?

One Way I am thinking to create QueryEngineFactory:

```
public class QueryEngineFactory
{
    private static final Map<String, QueryEngine> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void register(String schedulerName, QueryEngine scheduler){
        if(schedulerName!=null && scheduler!=null){
            schedulers.put(schedulerName, scheduler);
        }
    }

    public static QueryEngine getScheduler(String schedulerName){
        if(schedulers.containsKey(schedulerName)){
            return schedulers.get(schedulerName);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And Register the same while creating Engines not sure if it's correct or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example:

**QueryEngine interface**:

```
public interface QueryEngine {
    void runQuery(String Query);
    String type();
}
```

Some QueryEngine classes:

**FirstQueryEngine implementation**:

```
@Service
public class FirstQueryEngine implements QueryEngine {

    public static final String ENGINE_TYPE = "FirstQueryEngine";

    @Override
    public void runQuery(String Query) {
        System.out.println(ENGINE_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    public String type() {
        return ENGINE_TYPE;
    }
}
```

**SecondQueryEngine implementation**:

```
@Service
public class SecondQueryEngine implements QueryEngine {

    public static final String ENGINE_TYPE = "SecondQueryEngine";

    @Override
    public void runQuery(String Query) {
        System.out.println(ENGINE_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    public String type() {
        return ENGINE_TYPE;
    }
}
```

**ThirdQueryEngine implementation**:

```
@Service
public class ThirdQueryEngine implements QueryEngine {

    public static final String ENGINE_TYPE = "ThirdQueryEngine";

    @Override
    public void runQuery(String Query) {
        System.out.println(ENGINE_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    public String type() {
        return ENGINE_TYPE;
    }
}
```

And here is a simple factory which returns the correct `QueryEngine` given the `type`.

**QueryEngineFactory**:

```
@Service
public class QueryEngineFactory {

    @Autowired
    private List<QueryEngine> queryEngineList;

    public QueryEngine getQueryEngine(String type) {
        for (QueryEngine queryEngine: queryEngineList) {
            if (type.equals(queryEngine.type())) {
                return queryEngine;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now in your code you have to inject the `QueryEngineFactory` and ask it to give you the `QueryEngine` you want based on the `type`:

```
@Autowired
QueryEngineFactory queryEngineFactory;

...

final QueryEngine queryEngine = queryEngineFactory.getQueryEngine("FirstQueryEngine");
```

Comment: If I am doing this then any `Autowired`  in my  `FirstQueryEngine` is coming as null

Comment: I dont understand you comment, I have checked my proposal and it works. Can you elaborate please what is null? What are you trying to `@Autowired` in `FirstQueryEngine`? In my posted code I do not autowire anything there but since it is a spring managed bean, autowire should work

Comment: Let say I defining this thing :
`public static final String ENGINE_TYPE = "FirstQueryEngine";
@AutoWired
private SomeotherService service`

Comment: then `service` is coming null

Comment: This should work, `FirstQueryEngine` is annotated as `@Service` it is spring managed so autowiring other spring managed beans should work. However this depends on your app configuration, e.g. are you sure that the packages of these classes are scanned by spring to add them as bean during startup? Does `FirstQueryEngine` via `QueryEngineFactory` gets properly injected in your code i.e. it is not null and when you call the runQuery method it prints the text? If all these work then the problem is not in `FirstQueryEngine` but somewhere else in your code

Comment: Also are you sure that you inject (@Autowired) your QueryEngine or QueryEngineFactory beans and not initialize them via `new` e.g. `new QueryEngineFactory()` or `new FirstQueryEngine()`? If you are doing it with `new` then @Autowired is not going to work, you have to inject them via spring.